# Pointer to member variable - auto type in C++

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there is a way how to auto assign type of a pointer to member variable. I am trying something like:

```
struct DETECTOR
{
    Long64_t time;
    Double_t energy;
    Int_t number;
};

void member(string member_string)
{
    auto DETECTOR::*ptr;

    if(member_string == "time") ptr = &DETECTOR::time;
    if(member_string == "energy") ptr = &DETECTOR::energy;
    if(member_string == "number") ptr = &DETECTOR::number;

    //loop over a lot of DETECTOR objects and do some magic with them
}
```

but it's not working for obvious reason. I also cannot define *ptr* within IF statement since it would go out of scope.

The reason for this code is that I have a lot of DETECTOR objects that have to be processed in a loop but only based on user selected member variable. I don't want to have unnecessary if statements within that loop since I imagine that it would significantly reduce performance.

If there is another way how to do this, I would be grateful if you could point me to it. Thank you, I am eternal beginner in coding:).

EDIT:
sorry for not being clearer, I know why `auto DETECTOR::*ptr;` fails. I am looking for a workaround without if statements like this while looping over all `DETECTOR` objects.

```
DETECTOR det;
if(member_string =="energy") do_magic(det.energy)
if(member_string =="time") do_magic(det.time)
```

Comment: `ptr` type has to be known at compile time. If you insist on using single `ptr` variable -- you could use `std::variant`

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to _do_ with `ptr` later, but it seems like you're trying to use some trickery to avoid code repetition.  It's quite possible that you could do a cleaner job using templates or lambdas, rather than pointer-to-member.

Comment: Also, regarding your statement _"I imagine it would significantly reduce performance"_...  You know, it's wonderful to imagine.  But if you want to make decisions based on untested, unmeasured feelings, you might end up writing code that is harder to understand and maintain, whereas the simple solution might have had perfectly adequate performance.

Comment: @paddy About that statement, yes in this form you are definitely right that i should not base my code on some feelings, but I have around 150GB of data stored in different structs objects. Putting tons of if() there would ("i imagine") create a bottleneck.

Comment: `auto` is a shorthand for an implicit function template that would be called with the initializer: `auto` is only as powerful as a template. It can only generate types from an initializer.

Comment: Either your system has a LOT of RAM, or you are reading data from some other storage.  Again, if you _measure_ your if-statements to be the bottleneck, that's fine.  But it sounds to me like your program is I/O-bound.  Even if you did something pointlessly inefficient like testing strings everywhere instead of using an enum, I suspect you'll hardly notice the difference.

Comment: For any further help on this, you must show us _what_ you need to do.  As currently written, you have posed your question in the form of a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you have decided that the solution is pointer-to-member and have asked how to do that, when your _actual_ requirement is completely unspecified.

Comment: @paddy Yes, I am reading data from a storage. I will try the ugly brute string comparison as you are suggesting and let you know. Its just that for me as a beginner this solution waves a red flag as its ugly and its in crucial part of code which should be as fast as possible.

This problem is basically issue of knowing the exact name of the member variable in form of a string and wanting to get its value from within some object. Ideally without using a lot of if statements when iterating through the objects. Hope this make sense in my English!

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense.  Your problem would be much, much clearer if you showed relevant code instead of tiny snippets and unspecified operations like "do_magic".  People with years of programming experience under their belt will easily filter out the irrelevant stuff.  Your problem is the reverse: you have filtered out potentially relevant things, possibly thinking that it will add confusion.  The biggest source of confusion though, tends to be when inexperienced programmers try to use english to express code.  For a comprehensive answer that fits your current design, you need to show more.

Comment: @paddy I didn't want to put here relevant code because its messy and uses scientific libraries from CERN ROOT software toolkit that might not be that used around here. Another reason is that it is not actually fully implemented, its just me thinking a bit ahead if its actually doable. But thank you anyway, there already is a nice solution using lambda expression. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto` is not the solution you're looking for. Types in C++ cannot change at runtime. `auto` must always be inferred from it's initializer. In your case, there is no initializer so it won't work.

What I suggest to you would be to move the `auto` into the parameter of a lambda:

```
void member(string member_string)
{
    // Here, the type of `ptr` will be
    // inferred when the lambda is called
    //             ~~~~v~~~~
    auto do_magic = [](auto ptr) {
        // loop over objects and do some magic with them
    };

    if(member_string == "time") do_magic(&DETECTOR::time);
    if(member_string == "energy") do_magic(&DETECTOR::energy);
    if(member_string == "number") do_magic(&DETECTOR::number);
}
```

The lambda is the equivalent of a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void do_magic(T ptr) {
    // loop over objects and do some magic with them
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much good sir! I've never worked with lambdas before and so it took me a while to catch up but this is very elegant solution, just like I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use:

```
auto DETECTOR::*ptr;
```

since the `auto` part cannot be deduced without an initializer. E.g.

```
auto i = 10; // Type is deduced as int from 10.
auto j;      // Type cannot be deduced without an initializer.
j = 10;      // A subsequent assignment cannot be used to deduce type of j.
```

I am  not able to offer any more helpful suggestion without more knowledge of how you are using `ptr`.